# IOS - How to hide a view by touching anywhere outside of it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm new to IOS programming, I'm displaying a view when a button is clicked, using the following code inside the button method.

```
 @IBAction func moreButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.helpView.isHidden = false
    }
```

initially, the `self.helpView.isHidden` is set to true in `viewDidLoad` method to hide the view. Now, how can i dismiss this view by touching anywhere outside the view. From the research, i found that, it can be done by creating a transparent button that fits the whole viewController. So then by clicking on the button, we can make the view to dismiss. Can anyone give me the code in swift 3 to create such button.

Or, if there is any other better way to hide a view, it is welcomed.

I'm using Xcode 8.2, swift 3.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way you read should be good and easy enough to implement, you can also override `touchesBegan` and check if the touch view is the view or not/ or compare the touch position to hide it

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In touch began you should write like

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<AnyHashable>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch: UITouch? = touches.first
    //location is relative to the current view
    // do something with the touched point
    if touch?.view != yourView {
        yourView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. By doing this, the helpView doesn't dismiss by touching it. as expected.

Comment: May i know the exact issue

Comment: I want the helpView to dismiss only when we touch outside of that view, not by clicking on that view itself. So, i meant this code works exactly like i expected.

Comment: for swift 3: touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)

Comment: won't this not work if there's another view outside the view you want to dismiss?

Answer (score 13):

Swift 5.1:

This should help to dismiss the view once touched outside of the view.

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let touch = touches.first
        if touch?.view != self.yourView
        { self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @Santhosh. I appreciate your answer. It helped!

Comment: @iHarshil , Glad it helped. Anytime !!

Comment: An alternative version would be `touch?.view == defaultView`. `defaultView` is the full screen `UIView` (`Safe Area`'s parent) that XIB adds by default when you create a new `UIViewController` (use an outlet to get access). This view is always in the "background", so if you create e.g. a custom popup that doesn't fill the whole screen, "outside" is always that default view.

Answer (score 10):

**In Swift 4**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     let touch = touches.first
     if touch?.view == self.view {
        commentsTxtView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `touchesBegan` method for that:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.helpView.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<AnyHashable>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
     var touch: UITouch? = touches.first
     if touch?.view != self.yourView {
         self.yourView.isHidden = true
     }
 }
```

Objective C

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     if(touch.view != self.yourView){
         self.yourView.hidden = YES;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the moreButton selected, you can do something like this

```
 @IBAction func moreButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.helpView.isHidden = false
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissView))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissView() {
        self.helpView.isHidden = true
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. By adding this, i get two error. "Use of unresolved identifier 'tap'" and "Type 'UIViewController'  has no member 'dismissView'". I'm sure that i have added all codes that you suggested. Is there anything else i have to do ?

Comment: Hi. try typing view.view. I think youve assigned view = ViewController.

Comment: Also declare the "tap" outside the function. let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissView)) and then put  @IBAction func moreButton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.helpView.isHidden = false
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could create another transparent button or, your base view (assuming it's a single view below the button) can then address what you're trying to do. First, you would need to make it tappable. Then you want to handle the logic for what happens when tapped, or untapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want doing the following (tested with Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    private var dismissViewTap: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        dismissViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissView))

        if let tap = dismissViewTap {

            view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        } // if let

    } // viewDidLoad

    @objc private func dismissView() {

        guard let tap = dismissViewTap else {

            return

        } // guard

        guard helpView.isHidden == false else {

            return

        } // guard

        helpView.isHidden = true

        view.removeGestureRecognizer(tap)

    } // dismissView

    ...

} // ViewController
```

If you want to keep the gesture recognizer (maybe because you open helpView more than once) change dismissView to this version:

```
...

@objc private func dismissView() {

    guard helpView.isHidden == false else {

        return

    } // guard

    helpView.isHidden = true

} // dismissView

...
```

That's all...!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in swift 4.

> add the **tag** number to the **uiview** you want to add action

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if touches.first?.view?.tag == 10{
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        super.touchesEnded(touches , with: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case I followed it by touchesEnded logic,

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if([touch view]== self.UIViewThatNeedsToBeDismissed) {
        NSLog(@"inside view touch");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"release it");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function some this check on the view name will not work but if you have more than one view the problem you will see that if you tap inside your second view the same action will perform. I would prefer to add tapGesture. This is the other solution.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private func addClickToDismiss() {

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissPresentedView(_:)))
    tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    presentedViewController.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    presentedViewController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc
private func dismissPresentedView(_ sender: Any?) {
    presentedViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

If anyone wants some copy pasta, this is how you do it from a custom UIPresentationController