# check if user clicked outside view controller

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, gesture

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I would like to dismiss a view controller, if I clicked outside of this view controller.

With this code I can check, if the user has clicked into the view controller. but how can I check, if the user has clicked outside the view controller?

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
   let gesture = NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(clicked))
   gesture.buttonMask = 0x1 // left mouse
   gesture.numberOfClicksRequired = 1
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}


@objc func clicked() {
   print("Hello world")
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a different view inside your app's window(s) or outside the app entirely?

Comment: a view controller which will show as a sheet. if i clicked outside of this sheet view controller, i would like to dismiss this sheet view controller

Comment: @PhillipMills  I suggest it should be inside the app

Comment: yes inside the app

Comment: A view controller is not an interface element, so what does "click outside view controller" mean?

Comment: Sheets don't close when you click outside them. Add a close button or use a popover.

Answer (score 2):

`NSEvent` has a method called...

`+ (id)addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(NSEvent * _Nullable (^)(NSEvent *))block;`

...that captures events before they are dispatched.

Ask to monitor mouse up or mouse down events and use the block to compare the coordinates to your view's bounds.

Edit:

Except, in Swift, it's called...

`class func addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching mask: NSEventMask, handler block: @escaping (NSEvent) -> NSEvent?) -> Any?`

Answer (score 0):

Full swift version.

Add variable monitor

```
var monitor: Any?
```

Add in viewDidLoad

```
   monitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown) { (event) -> NSEvent? in
           let rect = self.view.convert(self.view.frame, to: event.window?.contentView)
           if !rect.contains(event.locationInWindow) {
                print("OUTSIDE")
           }
           return event
      }
```

deinit

```
 deinit {
      if monitor != nil {
           NSEvent.removeMonitor(monitor!)
           monitor = nil
      }
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use touchesEnded: then use the event to grab the locationInWindow. If the location falls outside your bounds of your view then dismiss it. A similar question for iOS can be seen here.

[IOS - How to hide a view by touching anywhere outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385450/ios-how-to-hide-a-view-by-touching-anywhere-outside-of-it)

I always prefer touchedEnded because if a user accidentally clicks outside they can still drag to the view to cancel the dismissal.

Comment: NEED OSX SOLUTION

Comment: That is why I said used touchesBegan/touchesEnded and check the NSEvent that is passed in for the locationInWindow variable...