# TouchesBegan always returns wrong UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

I want to detect when I'm touching somewhere else rather than a specific `UIView`. I'm using `touchesBegan` for it, however, it always prints "touch is outside" (see code below). What am I missing?

I got help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385450/ios-how-to-hide-a-view-by-touching-anywhere-outside-of-it).

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let hitView = self.view.hitTest(touch.location(in: self.view), with: event)
        if hitView === checkBackContainer {
            print("touch is inside")
        } else {
            print("touch is outside")
        }
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

Anchors added inside `ViewDidLoad` Function

```
private lazy var checkBackContainer = ImageUploadContainerView()

override func viewDidLoad(){
self.view.addSubview(checkBackContainer)
checkBackContainer.anchorCenterXToSuperview()
checkBackContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkFrontContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
checkBackContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
checkBackContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -25).isActive = true
checkBackContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkBackContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.42).isActive = true
checkBackContainer.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor.white, alpha: 1.0, x: 0, y: 0.33, blur: 1, spread: 0, cornerRadius: 6)

let backTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.backContainerTapped(_:)))
checkBackContainer.addGestureRecognizer(backTap) }
```

**EDIT:** ContainerView is a custom `UIView` which has some `UIStackView`s, `UIlabel`s and `UIImageView`s in it. I found that It is because a custom `UIView`, when I change it with a regular `UIView`. It is working.

Comment: try to add anchors in viewDidLayoutSubviews ... see  if makes a difference. But I suspect  checkBackContainer.anchorCenterXToSuperview() is the culprit anyway. Also try to bring  checkBackContainer  to front.

Comment: I also tried to give position with CGRect. When I do that , just a little point of the UIView detect the inside.

Comment: are the events you are getting belonging the child controls of the container view?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding UIGestureRecognizer to the views you want to be detected on touch:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTap(sender:)))
view1.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
view2.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

@objc func didTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
//Perform whatever you want in here
}
```

Alternatively, you can loop through all the subviews of parent view and exclude whatever views you want to exclude, like so:

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
   if view != viewYouWantToExclude {
      view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
   }
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to detect the touch outside of the view. With your code, I can only detect the view not outside of it.

Comment: Exactly, if you add gesture recognizer to all the views except the view you want to exclude, that is the functionality that you will get. It's arguably not the best approach, but it will definitely work.